# Cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this. I am trying to add auto-completion to my app with the Google Places API. I am following a tutorial and the following code is what I am having a problem with:

```
URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8") +
                "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=" +
                getResources().getString(R.string.googleAPIKey));
                URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        tc.getInputStream()));
```

The line "getResources()" is coming back with a "cannot resolve to a type" error because of the "R.string.googleAPIKey". I will put in my whole code down below:

```
package com.multinav;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_list);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (googleMap == null){
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (googleMap != null){
                setUpMap();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Set map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("BAAMMMM!"));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
public class Main extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public AutoCompleteTextView textview;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.item_list);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list);
            final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                    findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
             textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (count%3 == 1) {
    adapter.clear();
                    GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                            //now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                                    task.execute(textView.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    });
}

    class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
                   // three dots is java for an array of strings
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args)
    {

    Log.d("gottaGo", "doInBackground");

    ArrayList<String> predictionsArr = new ArrayList<String>();


    try
    {

        URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8") +
                "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key= +
                getResources().getString(R.string.googleAPIKey));
                URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        tc.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                                //take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                }
                                //turn that string into a JSON object
                JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); 
                               //now get the JSON array that's inside that object            
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                                        //add each entry to our array
                        predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                    }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    Log.e("MultiNAV", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);

    } 
    catch (JSONException e)
    {

    Log.e("MultiNAV", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);

    }

    return predictionsArr;

    }

    //then our post

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){

    Log.d("MultiNAV", "onPostExecute : " + result.size());
    //update the adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    //attach the adapter to textview
    textview.setAdapter(adapter); 

    for (String string : result){

    Log.d("MultiNAV", "onPostExecute : result = " + string);
    adapter.add(string);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    Log.d("MultiNAV", "onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter" + adapter.getCount());


        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Generally it's bad form to just hand us all your code. For future reference, read [http://www.sscce.org/]. Also, are you finding 'googleAPIKey' inside your auto-created/compiled class 'R'?

Comment: Thanks, I took out everything like my own API key, but I didn't think it would be bad knowing that I am following a tutorial.

Comment: No, my point is that you haven't done the legwork to find the smallest amount of code that demonstrates your problem. It's fine to give us a concise set of code that has an issue, but not fine to expect us to read through all your code. Especially because you didn't even bother to format it nicely for easy reading.

Comment: you missed the R import, ctrl-shift-o should fix

Comment: o my bad. I have asked many questions on stackoverflow and most people have always asked for my complete code. I just wanted to point out what part of the code I was having a problem with and then give my complete code for that activity to see if someone could help. I understand what you mean now and I appreciate or concern and comments.

Comment: did you fix your issue?

Comment: @blackbelt - I just tried this, and nothing happened when I tried the ctrl-shift-o. But I knew what you mean and tried to add the R import and when I did, it added like 20 errors of stuff that I have already fixed. Is this necessary?

Comment: @NathanielFord - to answer you first question though, I thought I added it, but I just realized that everytime that i have it added to the R.java file, I push save and it asks me if I want to keep these changes and I say yes and it then deletes it for some reason. What would cause this?

Comment: So, the android sdk writes to your R class configuration information it finds in your xml files. It will overwrite changes you make to that class directly. The problem here is that you probably failed to include this string (googleAPIKey) in an appropriate xml/layout/dictionary file and so it's not being put in your R class.

Comment: so how would I be able to fix this. I started doing some research on it and it seems as if most people add it to the string.xml file or they make a new class and call it "constants" and create a constant of the name they need. When I created the new class though, it allowed me to add it but I am still getting the error. Do I need to link something or what?

Comment: **UPDATE** - now I was able to fix my own issue. I simply made a new class and called it "Constants". Then I deleted the R.string.googleAPIKey part of the code and made it "Constants.googleAPIKey" and now it doesn't

Comment: cont>- give me any errors for that part. Now when I run my app, it gives me a runtime error, but i am about to research that. Thanks for everyone trying to help, or has helped, thanks.